# Windows 10 search "best match" delay (order issues)

Tags: windows, search, cortana, delay

I have a problem with the Windows 10 search feature. Currently running 1709 but I think it happens since 1607. The highest entry (best match) is changing for no reason.

For example I have Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code installed. When I type vis it used to find Visual Studio Code as first option. Now it displays Visual Studio and changes with a delay of ~500 msecs to Visual Studio Code. That happens for all applications and I tend to open like 50 applications a day I don't wanna start.

I don't have the problem on other machines. Already tried to rebuild the search index, sfc scannow, reinstalling/initializing Cortana via Powershell and can't find any other hints on how to solve that problem.